# Camera starts to lag when using setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer

Tags: android, android-camera

In my camera application I want to use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` instead of the normal `setPreviewCallback()` method. However, I noteced that when I use `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()` the camera preview starts to lag a couple of `ms` wheras when using `setPreviewCallback()` without any buffers the lag dous not occur. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Here is my source code of CameraView.

```
class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    private final String TAG = CameraView.class.getSimpleName();
    private final SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating Camera View.");
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(CameraView.this);
    }

    /**
     * Stopping cameraPreview
     */
    public void stopPreview() {
        if (isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Stopping Preview and releasing Camera.");
            isPreviewOn = false;
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SURFACE CREATED");
        //Some callback buffers to increase performance
        initBuffer();
        //start preview once the surface is created.
        try {
            //stopPreview();
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }

        //now it's time to initialize the ffmpeg recorder
        //initRecorder();
    }


    private void initBuffer() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialize Callback Buffers: " + BUFFER_SIZE);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
        mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CAMERA_PREVIEW_BUFFERS; i++) {
            mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Setting Camera parameters.
     */
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
        camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);
        camParams.setPreviewFpsRange(30000, 30000);
        mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
        startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            //mHolder.addCallback(null);
            mHolder.removeCallback(this);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(null);
        } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
        }
    }

    /**
     * Starting camera preview.
     */
    public void startPreview() {

        if (!isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting Preview.");
            isPreviewOn = true;
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        //...

        mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
    }

    private final int BUFFER_SIZE = (int) (imageWidth * imageHeight * 1.5);
    private final int NUM_CAMERA_PREVIEW_BUFFERS = 3;


}
```

Comment: Copying data around to work with it in a byte[] buffer adds overhead.  Is the slowdown more pronounced at larger preview resolutions?

Comment: Yes. And from time to time it suddenly stops to lag, and then slowly starts to begin again... I am using buffer in order to achieve a more stable frame rate.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?  I doubt you'll be able to keep up with 30fps video if you're making a copy of every frame into a byte[] buffer.